# htacces different rules for each sub-directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web-hosting

How could I give different access to sub-directories?

I have access only to htaccess directives for once, not to the httpd.conf of Apache.
And here are my folders:

```
~/www/
~/beta/ -> group betatesters developers
~/dev/ -> group developers
```

I would like to have only one .htaccess located in the root directory.

```
~/.htaccess
~/htpassd
~/htgroup
```

.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
AuthUserFile /home123/user321/htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /home123/user321/htgroup
<FilesMatch "beta">
    Require group betatesters developers
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "dev">
    Require group developers
</FilesMatch>
```

Any idea?

Sometimes the .htaccess file needs its own modifications, whereby is fully included in GIT repositories.

/WWW/, /DEV/, /BETA/ are just different versions in repos. That why I think it's unnatural to have a different htacces file in each folder. and it's annoying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on [Serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/311197/htacces-sub-directories/311261#311261). Follow the link to get it.

I should have done that from the beginning.